# perform operations on column cells one by one in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a date column inside a table which consists of distinct dates. I have to select the dates in each cell and perform some operation on them. What is the way to access the individual dates in the date column in SQL , So that i can perfom operations on each of those dates.
Can somebody give me a direction how to approach?

Comment: You need to post the schema for your database, some sample data, and some idea of what you want to do. From your question it's impossible to make any comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vogue. However it sounds like you need yo use update command with the following general structure -

`UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1 WHERE SOME_CONDITION;`